# D'où proviennent les participes passés terminant « -u » comme « lu, su, pu, vu, connu » etc. ?

Tags: grammaire, étymologie, participe-passé, latin

Je sais d'où proviennent les autres participes passés: « -é » du latin « -atum », « -i » du latin « -itum », comme

FIRMĀTUM [fɪrˈmaːtũ] -> [ferˈmado] -> [ferˈmaðə] -> [ferˈmaː] -> [fɛrˈme] -> [fɛʀˈme] « fermé »

FINĪTUM [fiːˈniːtũ] -> [fi'ni] « fini »

Mais quand je vois les participes passés latins des verbes comme « vendre, voir, lire », je vois VENDITUM VISUM, LECTUM.

Comment expliquer cela?

Comment: Ah, il y a des règles pour les verbes du 3ème groupe... ? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il y a un très petit nombre de verbes en latin classique qui formaient leur parfait en -u- et leur supin en -ūtum. Par exemple:

> Uoluere - uoluō - uoluī - uolūtum (rouler)
>
> Tribuere - tribuō - tribuī - tribūtum (répartir, accorder)
>
> Soluere - soluō - soluī - solūtum (détacher, délier)

Ils n'ont pas laissé grand trace en français contemporain: Je ne trouve que les verbes *battre*, *résoudre* et *dissoudre* comme descendants directs, le reste étant des emprunts plus tardifs, comme en témoigne leur infinitif en -er plutôt qu'en -re (attribuer, évoluer).

Le [u]/[w] de ces verbes ne faisait pas partie de leur système flexionnel, mais provenait de leur racine, et se retrouvait à tous les temps. Leur parfait se formait sans suffixe ou modification de la racine, mais simplement en ajoutant les suffixes personnels appropriés.

Un grand nombre d'autres verbes formaient par contre leur parfait avec un suffixe en /w/ (amāuī (j'aimai, racine amā-), dēbuī (je dus, racine dēb-), miscuī (je melangeai, racine misc-), seruīuī (je servis, racine seruī-)).

Les verbe réguliers comme *amāuī* et *seruīuī* avaient une voyelle thématique qui se retrouvait notamment au participe parfait : am**ā**tus et seru**ī**tum. Ce n'était par contre pas le cas pour des verbes dont la racine se terminait par une consonne, qui formaient leur participe en ajoutant -(i)tum au thème du présent : miscuī - mixtus ; dēbuī - dēbitus.

En latin vulgaire, le parfait en -u- des verbes à racine consonantale s'est confondu avec celui des verbes dont la racine se terminait par -u.

Les participes en -ūtum se sont ainsi étendus aux verbes dont le parfait se formait en -uī précédé d'une consonne :

> *Habere* (avoir) - parfait *hab**uī*** - participe *hab**i**tus* > * *hab**ū**tus*

Le phénomène a touché toute l'aire romane :

Habitum > Habūtum > av**u**to (italian) ; av**u**tu (corse, sicilien) ; av**u**t (roumain) ; av**u** (wallon, aussi yeu /jy/ à Charleroi) ; (h)ag**u**t (catalan, occitan) ; e**u** (français) ; v**û**t (friulan)

L'espagnol, le portugais et le sarde ont par contre des formes en /i/: hab**i**do ; hav**i**do et app**i**du, respectivement. Pour les langues ibères en tout cas, il s'agit d'une évolution antérieure, des participes en -udo étant attestés dans la langue médiévale, mais [ayant fini par disparaître](https://ubir.buffalo.edu/xmlui/handle/10477/51292) au XVème siècle.

En français, /'u:.tũ/ a évolué en /'y/ et est devenu avec /e/ et /i/ un des suffixes du participe passé. Il restait cependant en ancien français un nombre important de participes passés irréguliers, qui ont depuis été régularisés en participes en -u (les deux autres suffixes sont sans doute trop associés aux verbes en -er et en -ir pour se répandre aux verbes irréguliers). L'ancienne forme du participe subsiste souvent comme substantif:

> course (lat. cursum) - couru
>
> mors (lat. morsum) - mordu
>
> tort (lat. torsum, a.fr. tors) - tordu

L'alternance entre *mort* et *mouru* n'est que le prolongement normal de ce processus.

Cette évolution explique tous ces verbes en français moderne qui forment leur passé simple en /i/ (> lat. uī) et leur participe passé en /y/ (v.lat. ūtum).

Comme le montrent le passé simple de battre (il se battit) et de *soldre* en ancien français (sousismes >< nous (ré)solûmes), le -u- du parfait, atone, n'a jamais survécu. Les verbes qui ont en français moderne un thème en u au passé simple et au subjonctif imparfait ont été reformés sur la base de leur participe passé.

---

Les trois verbes mentionnés dans la question n'ont cependant pas de parfait en -uī (*uēndidī*, *uīdī* et *legī*), et requièrent un peu plus de réflexion.

D'après [ce tableau des conjugaisons de l'ancien français](https://juliettebourdier.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/tableaux-de-conjugaison-de-lancien-franc3a7ais.pdf):

*Vendre* avait comme participe des formes en /y/ uniquement : vendu, vandu, vendut, vandut ; vuendu ; vanduit

*Veoir* avait comme participe des formes en /y/ uniquement: veü, vehu, veüt, veüd ; vedud ; vaü ; voüt, voüd ; veu

*Lire* avait comme participe des formes en /i/ et en /y/ à la fois: lit ; liet ; leit ; leüt, leü ; liut, liu ; lieut ; lut ; lui ; luit. (*Leit* me semble être le descendant normal de lēctum > */lekto/ > */lexto/ > */lejt/, sur le modèle de noctem > nuit et de factum > fait)

Le remplacement analogique des participes irréguliers avait donc commencé bien avant que le français ne commence à s'écrire.

Answer (score 2):

D'après Grevisse (*Le bon usage*, 14e ed., §808), un grand nombre de verbe irréguliers (notamment la quasi-totalité des verbes en -dre) on tout simplement vu leurs participes passés irréguliers être remplacés par des participes en -u par analogie avec les participes passée résultant de la finales latine -utum. E.g. *mors, pers, tors* → *mordu, perdu, tordu*. (D'où, d'ailleurs, le mot *tort*, à l'origine une variante de *tors*.)