# Past participles of "devenir" and "sortir."

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, participe-passé

If the past participle of *devenir* is "devenu" so the "ir" is replaced with a "u", then why is *sortir* (which also ends with "-ir") replaced with an "i"?

Comment: Related:  [D'où proviennent les participes passés terminant « -u » comme « lu, su, pu, vu, connu » etc. ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19061/do%c3%b9-proviennent-les-participes-pass%c3%a9s-terminant-u-comme-lu-su-pu-vu)

Comment: @jlliagre That was an interesting Q&A, thanks for the reminder,  but probably way too difficult for the OP, this is surely a beginner's question.

Answer (score 2):

*Sortir* and *devenir* have different conjugations. Regular verbs (those whose conjugation obey to a pattern) can be divided into three groups, those with an infinitive that ends in *er* (like *chanter*), those with an infinitive that ends in *ir* (like *finir*), those with an infinitive that ends in *re* (like *vendre*). And there's a bunch of **irregular verbs that do not follow a pattern, *devenir* and *sortir* belong to those**. Some irregular verbs have an infinitive ending in *er* others in *ir* other in *re*, so when you learn a new verb you never can tell if it's regular or irregular at first sight.
When you learn a new verb you'd better check if it's regular or not, and if it's irregular then you know you will have to learn how to conjugate it as you learn new tenses. You can work out the past participle of a regular verb knowing its infinitive, but for an irregular verb you have to learn it when you learn how to conjugate it.

You can have a look and [wiktionary's page on French irregular verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:French_irregular_verbs) and and this page [How to Conjugate Irregular –ir French Verbs](http://www.dummies.com/languages/french/how-to-conjugate-irregular-ir-french-verbs/). There are lots of sites on the internet where you will find the conjugation of verbs, for example [this one](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/devenir.php).

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! I understand now, thanks.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD  I am **not** making it sound, I hope I am saying it very explicitly.  I am  talking from a foreign learner's perspective. This is how French as a foreign language is usually taught. The classification into three groups (-er, -ir, and irregular) is the classical description from a French native perspective.  I have given a link in my answer, [here's an another one](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/introduction-to-verbs/)  saying French regular verbs can be classified  into three groups. You may not like my point of view but saying it is **not  accurate** needs to be proved.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD We entirely agree they are conventions. That is why **I am asking you** to justify that saying regular verbs can be divided into three groups, (-er, -ir, and -re) is not accurate. I have nothing to clarify, **I** am not the one saying my perspective is the only one or the best, as I said before : you are allowed  not to like my point of view, but if you say it is wrong you have to say why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the evolution of *sortir* ([the Latin verb it descends from](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sortior) had no participle forms), but the past participle of the verb that evolved into *devenir* was *deventus*, which eventually gave the *-u* in modern french.